# AJAX Multiples submit en un form

Tags: html, jquery, html5, ajax

Necesito tener 2 o más botones en un **FORM** y cada uno con una acción diferente, se que esto puedo hacerlo directamente con **HTML** agregando a los botones un **formaction** pero necesito hacer esto desde **AJAX**, tambien estoy conciente de que puedo usar un **onclick** en cada boton, pero necesito que sea mediante un **submit** para que **html** se encargue de hacer todas las validaciones del formulario, ya que hay campos con los atributos required, maxlength, email, number, etc.

Seria algo asi lo que necesito:

```
$(function(){
  $('form').submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   /*Codigo Ajax*/
  });
});

<form>
 <input type="text" name="usuario" required/>
 <input type="password" name="password" required/>
 <button formaction="login.php"></button>
 <button formaction="registro.php"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Y... ¿Cuál es el problema? Deberías añadir tu código. Si vas a usar AJAX, de todos modos vas a tener que capturar el evento submit y cancelarlo... puedes leer el *action* en ese momento

Comment: y el html con el formulario?, no lo veo como para darle contexto a esto.

Comment: @SebastiánLagosYañez No hace falta que coloque el codigo del formulario, puedo poner el formulario que sea, lo que necesito es que html haga las validaciones de todos los campos usando 2 botones tipo SUBMIT (Cada boton debe tener un formaction diferente)

Comment: El /*Codigo Ajax*/ puede ir antes del submit? Lo que digo es, ejecuta ese código y luego hace el submit. Porque si es asi haces un .on click de cada btn y luego el submit del form

Comment: Simplemente usa un div y no un form, o selecciona por evento click de los botones dentro del formulario y no este en sí. Al hacer esto, el event target será el botón y podrás identificarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar `document.activeElement` para obtener cuál fue el botón que se utilizó y luego obtener el `formaction` con el método `.attr()` de jQuery.

```js
$(function(){
  $('form').submit(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var action = $(document.activeElement).attr('formaction');
   
   // imprime "login.php" o "registro.php"
   console.log(action);
   
   /*Codigo Ajax*/
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
 <input type="text" name="usuario" required/>
 <input type="password" name="password" required/>
 <button formaction="login.php">login</button>
 <button formaction="registro.php">registro</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pude resolver este tema gracias al plugin de jquery **jqueryvalidation**
es increiblemente facíl de usar.

El codigo quedó de la siguiente manera:

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  });

  function Registro(){
    /*
       EL PLUGIN HACE LAS VALIDACIONES DEL 
       FORMULARIO Y RETORNA TRUE O FALSE
    */ 

    if( $("form").valid() ){
      /* CODIGO AJAX PARA REGISTRAR USUARIO */
    }
  }

  function Login(){
    /*
       EL PLUGIN HACE LAS VALIDACIONES DEL 
       FORMULARIO Y RETORNA TRUE O FALSE
    */ 

    if( $("form").valid() ){
      /* CODIGO AJAX PARA INICIAR SESION */
    }
  }
</script>

 <form>
   <input type="text" name="usuario" required/>
   <input type="password" name="password" required/>
   <button type="button" onclick="Login()">Iniciar Sesion</button>
   <button type="button" onclick="Registro()">Registro</button>
 </form>
```